# How can I have Asymptote rescale a drawing automatically to fit a width

Tags: asymptote

In working on the [Mathics documentation](https://mathics.org/docs/mathics-latest.pdf), I realize what I'd like to do is have Asymptote layout and "draw" its figure then have it compute its width and then rescale the X and Y dimensions down (or up) to fit the width of the column it needs to render in.

Thoughts on how to do?

Comment: Hi.  I don't have time to give you a working example right now.  However, if you read the "frame" and "picture" sections of the manual, you can see that there are functions to fit a picture within a given size.  I think you will need to draw your figure to a picture besides the currentpicture.  For example "picture p;"  Then "draw(p, unitsquare);"  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will check this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of fitting a picture to a specific size using the following function from the "Frames and pictures" section of the manual.

```
frame pic.fit(real xsize=pic.xsize, real ysize=pic.ysize, bool keepAspect=pic.keepAspect);
```

The following code creates a picture named "p", then adds it to the currentpicture twice, once as defined, and once fit to 1.5 inches wide.  The black squares are both 1.5 inches wide.

```
unitsize(1inch);

picture p; // create a new picture named "p"
filldraw(p, unitcircle, palered, 8+red); // draw a circle on "p"
label(p, "Test", (0,0), red); // create a label on "p"

add(shift(-2,0)*p);  // add "p" to the currentpicture
draw(shift(-2,0)*scale(1.5)*shift(-0.5,-0.5)*unitsquare);

add(p.fit(72*1.5)); // add "p" to the currentpicture, but fit to 1.5 inches wide
draw(scale(1.5)*shift(-0.5,-0.5)*unitsquare);
```

[image]

NOTES:

1. The "72" scale used in the "fit" function is used to convert from inches to pixels.  I don't really understand why it's needed, but it is.
2. The "fit" function is not reducing the thickness of the red circle.
3. The "fit" function is not reducing the font size.
4. If a label is the left-most or right-most object, the "fit" function doesn't seem to work properly as shown below.

[image]

SUMMARY:  Create a picture "p", draw on picture "p", then add picture "p" using the `add(p.fit(72*width));` function.